# Rails 4.2 rollback transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, clockwork

clockworkを使って定期処理を実装したのですが、トランザクションロールバックしてしまいます。どうすれば直るでしょうか？なんのトランザクションがロールバックしているのでしょうか？ちなみにローカル環境下では定期処理自体は動いています。

**ログ**

```
 (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "items" WHERE "items"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND ("items"."limit_day" BETWEEN '2013-12-24 00:00:00.000000' AND '2015-05-28 17:10:36.818442') AND "items"."trade" = 't' AND "items"."limit_check" = 'f'
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "items" WHERE "items"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND ("items"."limit_day" BETWEEN '2013-12-24 00:00:00.000000' AND '2015-05-28 17:11:36.916917') AND "items"."trade" = 't' AND "items"."limit_check" = 'f'
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "items" WHERE "items"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND ("items"."limit_day" BETWEEN '2013-12-24 00:00:00.000000' AND '2015-05-28 17:12:36.602979') AND "items"."trade" = 't' AND "items"."limit_check" = 'f'
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "items" WHERE "items"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND ("items"."limit_day" BETWEEN '2013-12-24 00:00:00.000000' AND '2015-05-28 17:13:36.908669') AND "items"."trade" = 't' AND "items"."limit_check" = 'f'
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "items" WHERE "items"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND ("items"."limit_day" BETWEEN '2013-12-24 00:00:00.000000' AND '2015-05-28 17:13:44.742769') AND "items"."trade" = 'f' AND "items"."limit_check" = 'f'
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "items" WHERE "items"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND ("items"."limit_day" BETWEEN '2013-12-24 00:00:00.000000' AND '2015-05-28 17:14:36.719051') AND "items"."trade" = 't' AND "items"."limit_check" = 'f'
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "items" WHERE "items"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND ("items"."limit_day" BETWEEN '2013-12-24 00:00:00.000000' AND '2015-05-28 17:15:36.733665') AND "items"."trade" = 't' AND "items"."limit_check" = 'f'
   (0.3ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "items" WHERE "items"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND ("items"."limit_day" BETWEEN '2013-12-24 00:00:00.000000' AND '2015-05-28 17:16:36.400022') AND "items"."trade" = 't' AND "items"."limit_check" = 'f'
```

**lib/tasks/item.rake**

```
namespace :item do
  desc "TODO"
  #アイテムのリミットとトレードチェック取引ナビ作成
  task trade_limit_end_item_check: :environment do


    no_check_item = Item.where(limit_day: Time.mktime(2014, 12, 24, 00, 00, 00).prev_year..Time.now, trade: true, limit_check: false)


    if no_check_item.count > 0
      Item.transaction do
        no_check_item.find_each do |item|

          #該当ユーザ
          warrant = Warrant.find_by(item_id: item.id)


          #取引ナビ生成
          navi = Navi.create(exhibitor_id: item.user_id, proprietor_id: warrant.holder_id, item_id: item.id, status: false, score_judge: true, score_body:'')

          #お知らせ一覧 取引ナビお知らせ
          Todo.create(exhibitor_id: item.user_id, proprietor_id: warrant.holder_id, item_id: item.id, navi_id: navi.id, body_num: 90000, status: false)

          #ループ中のcreateのパフォーマンスも気になるようであれば、activerecord-importというgemを利用する

          #アイテムタイムリミットチェックフラグ
          item.update({limit_check: true, phase: 20000})
        end
      end
    end
  end





  #アイテムタイムリミッチェック
  task limit_day_check: :environment do


    limit_day_end_item = Item.where(limit_day: Time.mktime(2014, 12, 24, 00, 00, 00).prev_year..Time.now, trade: false, limit_check: false)


    if limit_day_end_item.count > 0
      Item.transaction do
        limit_day_end_item.find_each do |item|


          #アイテムタイムリミットチェックフラグ
          item.update({limit_check: true, phase: 10010})

        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**lib/clock.rb**

```
require 'clockwork'
include Clockwork

every(60.second, 'trade_limit_end_item_check.job') do
   puts `rake item:trade_limit_end_item_check`
end


every(300.second, 'limit_day_check.job') do
  puts `rake item:limit_day_check`
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ログを見る限り `if no_check_item.count > 0` が常に `false` になって更新処理（ifブロックの中身）が全く走っていないように見えますね。

rails console等で

```
Item.where(limit_day: Time.mktime(2014, 12, 24, 00, 00, 00).prev_year..Time.now, trade: false, limit_check: false)
```

が1件以上のデータを返すか確認してみてください。

また更新処理が走らないのであればトランザクションは大した意味を持たないので、commitされようが、rollbackされようが特に気にする必要は無いと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。該当するアイテムがある場合はちゃんと作動するのですが、rollbackが気になるので質問させていただきました。

Answer (score 0):

```
transaction do
...
end
```

の中では例外が起こった時点でrollbackします。
なので、私がtransactioinを行うときは下記のようにしています。

```
begin
  transaction do
    no_err = true
    @item = Item.new(params[:item])
    no_err = @object.save

    @order = Order.find_by(id: params[:order][:id])
    no_err = @order.update_attributes(params[:order])

    raise unless no_err
  end
rescue => e
  p e
  p @item.errors
  p @order.errors
else
  #...
end
```

上記のように例外処理の中でインスタンスのerrorsを確認するようにして
デバッグしてみるのはいかがでしょう。